Current limitation in hair electrolysis removal circuit
NOTE:  Added by moderator.
The voltages and currents when applied as described in this question (no more than 9 VDC) would be considered safe under almost any regulatory system. Higher voltages and currents and/or puncturing the surface skin with an electrode in the vicinity of the heart may have dangerous consequences.

Galvanic electrolysis is a technique of permanent hair removal where an electrode is applied to the hair follicle. The chemical reaction results in lye produced which destroys the follicle.

Voltage used is 9V DC.

Target current is 0.1mA to 0.8mA


Some folks have designed diy circuits and I am concerned by the fact that their designs assume the resistance of the body is that of wet skin (around 7000 Ohm). What if the needle is accidentally probed into a blood vessel. That will drop the resistance down to, say, 200 Ohms, and given the same voltage source, might drive lethal currents.
Now I imagined that instead of relying on the body to provide the bulk of resistance, and add whatever extra is needed using a resistor in series to drive a suitable current, isn't a design where the body's resistance in a very minor contribution and the bulk from the resistor better?
Normally the patient (or yourself, in diy) keep a salty wet sponge under your foot to complete the circuit. So the current pathway is from hair follicle to foot with sponge. That means, if the hair is on your left arm, the current pathway will include the heart! I expect a design where a ground wet salty sponge is attached to an area close to the hair follicle being treated, with the feet insulated from ground, a better way to protect the heart and vital organs. This obviously will bring the resistance down a great deal, given the short distance between the "terminals". But we can always attach a much larger resistor in series, and since that is fixed, it will also take care of the possible high current issue.
The usual (dangerous) circuit

My proposed (hopefully safer) circuit, where R is much greater than the R in above circuit.

Is my train of thought correct? What is a possible fault situation in my hopefully better safer setup?
EDIT 1: On @RussellMcMahon request, I state that the voltage source is 9V DC, and the intended current should never exceed 0.8mA. I am open to complex circuitry involving op amps, FET's, MOSFET's, transistors and such, but please ALSO give a comment on my presented setup above.

You could use a current source instead of a voltage source + resistance. That way you do not need to make any assumptions regarding the body resistance. Disclaimer:I have no experience in medical electronics.

Your train of thought regarding changing the terminal position sounds reasonable to me but again, I am no expert and given that the subject is a person, I think it would make sense to add more circuit complexity and ensure that there is no risk.

What voltage ? What target current? Killing people is surprisingly easy. Sometimes it doesn't happen for enough trials that people become blasé / assume it is safe. || We can give good answers with enough information. As it is we don't know if we are offering advice that may make us morally and/or legally culpable for damage caused. SO Please answer at least the two above questions. || A current source need not be complex or difficult.  ||NOTE Due to the issues involved I will close this question if more detail is not provided promptly. Not wanting to seem harsh, but, its important.

This is not the type of device to DIY. Medical electronics are subject to strict requirements and thats not for fun. It's because the human body is complex, and potential risks can have fatal outcomes. Development of medical devices actually to be used on living things should be left to those who have the proper competence, imo.

@RussellMcMahon Voltage is 9V DC only,  target current is stated in question. And instead of closing the question, please give a good answer. It will save lives! Lack of information is mostly why diy'ers get into trouble. Not having information doesn't stop them. Mind as well provide our best discussion so they can use it.

@Velvet Sorry if that sounded careless, but I genuinely don't mean to avoid those components. I'm just also interested in knowing whether this suggested design of mine is significantly BETTER (not absolute best) than the usual diy setup. Human lives aren't meant to be played with, but diy'ers lurk here in the forums and so, your honest replies will teach them the best way.

In my understanding, the worst possible situation is where the resistance of the body goes down to zero. If the fixed resistor is large enough, we can place the terminals on the body so close to each other that we can design the circuit as if the body was indeed 0 Ohms. That way, the constant voltage source will only drive what we calculated of I=V/R. Yes, assume the resistor is in good shape and hasn't shorted itself.

The current limit for medical devices is something like 100uA, anything more and it's considered dangerous

My stack exchange answer here provides a very detailed discussion of the dangers incurred by applying low voltages (say 12 VDC) to the body in various manners. The cited references, including

A review of hazards associated with exposure to low voltages
A review of hazards associated with exposure to low voltages
Dr. Marom Bikson
Department of Biomedical Engineering, City College of New York of the City
University of New York
The Graduate School and University Center of the City University of New York
New York, N.Y


and

Electrocution related fatalities

Make it very clear that fatal electrocution can occur with extremely low voltage sources and, very importantly, the conditions under which such events occur are very rare and require exceptional circumstances.
This article  cited in my prior answer provides this diagram. This relates to "GFCI" equipment which breaks contact under shock conditions but is useful here. Current is on the X axis and acceptable skin application lie on the Y axis. Currents of under 6 mA via the skin have application time regulatory requirements of 2+ seconds. Note the red heart fibrillation curve - far higher currents for much longer durations.

So
I would hazard a professional guestimate, with no certainty that I was correct and no responsibility taken that:

The usual method of wet sponge under foot is unwise but almost certainly not going to cause a fatality.  Not using it hear the heart and not puncturing the skin there "would be wise" but if currents are kept to the maximum level stated the dangers are very very very low.

and that

Your described method sounds safer again. If a small 9V "PP3" transistor radio battery is used with a series resistor of say 1000 Ohms then maximum possible current is I = V/R = 9/1000 = 9 mA which is not dangerous if applied to the skin surface.

Two sharp electrodes pushed into the skin adjacent to the heart "just may" cause problems but in most cases the sharp electrode issues would predominate. It's certainly not something that you should try.

Currents in the microamps level applied internally in the vicinity of the heart can be fatal.



Sigh, I had forgotten about this place since the question was closed. Never knew it can re-open...

Your write-up was very interesting. I still am confused as to whether current can pass through your heart if the two electrodes, EVEN IF they have punctured the skin, are a centimeter apart from each other and this place being, say, your forearm or calves. There is no path to ground from the (-)ive terminal through your heart if you wear rubber sandals, except that of the other adjacent electrode. Even if there was, it would have a resistance way larger than of the short path between electrodes, thus majority of current would flow safely. Could cause burns, sure, but death?!

@ElFlea the current you are talking about is extremely small by electric shock measures. See graph in my answer. You are not going to cause burns from momentary  into skin injection but of course it's inadvisable.. If you left the electrodes in your skin you would form very sow elevtrolysis which would leave some sort of adverse results but probably relatively minor. I would be very very very very surprised if doing such thing caused heart issues. You can for example apply a 9 volt battery to your tongue. This is quite unpleasant but I have ...

never ever heard of its causing any adverse effects in the body. I test nine volt batteries this way very very occasionally.

I know it the current I talk about is extremely small. I'm confused about you mentioning that such currents applied INTERNALLY can cause ventricular fibrillation. Now is it even physically possible for current at all going to your heart if the voltage is applied between two very close points on an extremity like the forearm? I believe there is NO chance of even minor electrical current to the heart. Even if everything failed, the circuit shorted say, the skin/tissue between the electrodes would burn, but the heart would be safe, right?

Say you stick one needle connected to a 9V battery 2mm deep in the skin on your leg calf, and another gel electrode on the same calf 3 cm away from the needle electrode. You connect a 30K resistor in series. As I=V/R, current would be 0.3mA (assume resistance of flesh/skin between electrodes is zero). Now can the heart in any way be affected by such a setup? Even if circuit is shorted somehow, the current will still flow BETWEEN the electrodes. The path does not include the heart! There is physically no way. Path of least resistance is still the flesh between, not through the heart.

@ElFlea I'd consider it "completely safe". I'd expect even a far smaller resistor to be acceptable. I did not mention ventricular fibrillation as such but that is what one wishes to avoid. I mentioned heart currents for completeness BUT they are really highly irrelevant here. I'd rate your oversall setup as being about as safe as you could get with anything applying a battery to skin - and that is very safe indeed.  I amnot a medical professional. I have carried out a long term exchange on this list noting that in very very worst case conditions 12V applied on the chest surface across ...

... the heart HAS killed. This is exceptionally rare. Numerous people claim it is completely impossible. It's not, but, again, it is very very very rare indeed.  Your arrangement is tens of times safer again. As I noted, I occasionally "test" 9V batteries for liveness wit my tongue. Not recommended ! :-) . My tongue is closer to my heart than your electrodes and also close to my spine. I have no fear of tongue testing at 9V causing cardiac issues.  Impotnat - I'll add it as a separate comment as it is of general value -->

"The path of  least resistance" is a simplistic description that is a very very very poor model of reality. Current DOES NOT take the path of least resistance. If a voltage is applied between points  A" and "B"  and there are several independent paths available current will flow along ALL avaiable paths in inverse proportion to their resistance. In each case I = V/R where R is the path resistance. If there is one path of much lower resistance than others MOST current will flow via it BUT for a non current limited source current will also flow via the other paths independent of the main path.

Very good point about the "path of least resistance". I knew that and had it in mind all along. The thing is, in my scenario, the voltage between A and B is such the physical conductive path between A and B does not contain the heart. Like parallel loops in a circuit still need to be connected to a voltage across each. Then the resistances determine how much current flows through each. But here, the heart does not have a voltage across is in the first place!

Also, to make it even safer, could we use a manual switch which connects a charging circuit with battery to a capacitor and a discharging circuit with the charged capacitor as voltage provider and 30K resistor in series with body. The operator will manually switch on/off to deliver the current to the hair. The capacitor will discharge quickly, so I think it will be even safer, should a fault happen somewhere.

Please answer my comments.

@ElFlea You have enough already in the many comments above. || See my added note at the top of your question. || See the my diagram https://i.sstatic.net/zO0t4OO5.png in my answer and the related link. If your device operates in the region below the bottom of the lower curve of 3 (Class A GFCI) it is consideredsafe AND it always will operate in this area except if you stick electrodes deeply into the skin very close to the heart - which of course is not on your list of "how to use" :-) :-( . Even then it MAY be OK.
